# Passing from values to a php function on post

Tags: php, html

For some reasons I can not get variables from the form to the next page send.php I tried to echo them but I can not see the output. The use enters the date period t1 is lower period while t2 is upper. Then enters the message on the text-box. On submit, the date period is inserted to the db select statement to select the contacts. Then together with the message they are passed to sendbulk function. I can't get these variables. Anyone spot something?

```html
<FORM ACTION="send.php" METHOD="POST"> 
 <input type="text" name="t1" id="t1" placeholder="start"> 
 <img src='calendar.jpg'  onClick="start_cal('t1','calendar1');";>  
<div id="calendar1" style=""></div>

<input type="text" id="t2" name="t2" placeholder="stop"> 
 <img src='calendar.jpg'  onClick="start_cal('t2','calendar2');";>  
<div id="calendar2" style=""></div><br>
Your Message:<BR> 

<TEXTAREA NAME="message" COLS=50 ROWS=6></TEXTAREA> <P>
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Send Message"> 
</FORM>
```

```
//send.php has the following code
   $message_sent = $_POST['message'];
   $t1 = $_POST['t1']; 
   $t2 = $_POST['t2'];

  //create database connection 

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT msisdn FROM customer WHERE time_paid BETWEEN '$t1' AND '$t2'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); // fetch data

  $mobilenumber = $resultarr['msisdn'];
  echo "$mobilenumber"; echo "<br>";


sendbulk();

function sendbulk() {


 global $message_sent;
 global $mobilenumber;

   echo "$message_sent";
   echo "$mobilenumber";
 $serviceArguments = array(
           "mobilenumber" => $mobilenumber,
           "message" => $message_sent
        );

$client = new SoapClient("http://.......");

$result = $client->process($serviceArguments);
$conn->close();

return $result;


}
```

Comment: function sendbulk ($param1, $param2, $param3, ...){}

Comment: then call function: sendbulk($param1, $param2, ...);

Comment: So what arguments am I to pass in the function sendbulk? the $mobilenumber is processed outside the function while the message_sent is to be sent as is from the text area to the sendbulk function. @B.Kocaman

Comment: See my answer, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below example;

```
<?php
//send.php has the following code
$message_sent   = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : 'There is no message';
$t1             = isset($_POST['t1']) ? $_POST['t1'] : 'default something';
$t2             = isset($_POST['t2']) ? $_POST['t2'] : 'default something';

//create database connection

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT msisdn FROM customer WHERE time_paid BETWEEN '$t1' AND '$t2'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($rowcount > 0){
    $resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); // fetch data
    $mobilenumber = $resultarr['msisdn'];

    // parameters goes in function...
    sendbulk($mobilenumber, $message_sent); 
}else{
    echo 'Opppss!!! There is no result.';
}


function sendbulk($mobilenumber, $message_sent) {
    global $conn;
    echo "$message_sent";
    echo '<br />';
    echo "$mobilenumber";
    $serviceArguments = array(
        "mobilenumber" => $mobilenumber,
        "message" => $message_sent
    );

    $client = new SoapClient("http://.......");

    $result = $client->process($serviceArguments);
    $conn->close();

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: How is that different from the OP's code? I think you should add some explanations about the changes you made.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take basic example i don't know why is this happening but the procedure is

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="send.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="t1" id="t1" placeholder="start">  
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"> 
</form>
```

Here **enctype="multipart/form-data"** you can use if you want to send images
On send.php you check  **$_POST**  by **print_r($_POST)** it will print you all the things which are you posting and receive in send,php page by

```
$t1   = isset($_POST['t1']) ? $_POST['t1'] : 'There is no t1';
```

Or Simply like this

```
 $t1 = $_POST['ti'] //then next procedures
```